# How can I hide the player on iOS lockscreen caused by an audio tag in Safari?

Tags: html, ios, audio, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I am trying to hide the complete player in the iOS Lockscreen. I am using an audio tag in a web application. These guys made it somehow work: https://energy.ch/. You will see when you test it on iOS.